# Is it possible to perform a mathematical operation based on a string input?

Tags: python, math, counter

I just made a quick counter in Python where you just have to type in the following numbers, one by one (as some of you might have seen on some Discord servers)

I wanted to make it more interesting by adding the possibility of typing mathematical operations in the input, so that if the next number is **3** you can type **2+1**, but it didn't go well.

This is the original code:

```py
contador = 0
operaciones = ["+","-","*","/"]

while True:
    if contador == 0:
        numero = int(input("¡Comenzamos! Estamos en 0: "))
        if numero == contador + 1:
            contador = numero
        else:
            print("¡Has perdido!")
            break

    numero = int(input("Introduce el siguiente número: "))
    if numero == contador + 1:
        contador = numero
    else:
        print("¡Has perdido!")
        break
```

When running it, this is the error message I get:
`invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2+1'`
Then I tried changing the inputs to string instead of int, but it just wouldn't work.

Comment: There is [SimpleEval](https://github.com/danthedeckie/simpleeval), a python module which was developed [following a similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string/35930111#comment30398812_9558001)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the `eval()` function:

```
print(eval('2 + 1'))
```

will print 3!

Also, it works to convert strings to other types of variables!

By the way, it can be very dangerous if you put a string of functions that can, for example, delete your files, so be careful.

Comment: Never suggest `eval` without mentioning that this might be the most dangerous function in Python. Please read: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: You can use the `pure-eval` library for a safer alternative.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are trying to **get the entire string as int** - that is not possible, because you're not thinking about the operators.

This **regex** matches one or more digits `(\d+)` followed by one of the four basic math operators `([±/*])` followed by one or more digits `(\d+)`.

```py
import re
string = input("¡Comenzamos! Estamos en 0: ")
pattern = r"(\d+)([+-\/*])(\d+)"
match = re.match(pattern, string)
if match:
    num1 = match.group(1) # "2"
    op = match.group(2) # "+"
    num2 = match.group(3) # "1"
```

Comment: The current documentation for literal_eval indicates that "safe" is not entirely true.  While it won't evaluate python code like eval will, it still can be dangerous to run on untrusted input.

Comment: Yes you're right. I edited the sentence to not make it sound like its 100% safe.

Comment: I got `ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.BinOp object at 0x...>` using `ast.literal_eval('2+1')`, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is use eval() as said by @pirosow, but please take care because in this way you may encounter dangerous inputs (code execution or exceptions due to bad inputs).

In other words, I wont raccomend eval(). Take a look on librieries like pandas or sympy may be a more solid choice if you don't want to manually parse string inputs.